# Custom Attribute on Category Page not Displaying

Tags: magento-1.7, category-attribute

I'm trying to add a custom attribute to the category page to show/hide product prices for individual categories.

I was trying to follow this tutorial, but I can't seem to get the field to display on the category page in the Dashboard.

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/add-custom-attribute-dropdown-category-section-magento/

I can see the plugin installed in `System >> Configuration >> Advanced` and it's enabled. I've also cleared cache and reindexed.

Comment: Check your `core_resource` table for an entry for `add_category_attribute`. If its there, delete it and refresh your cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I had to delete the entry in the `core_resource` table and make sure the plugin was set to `local` not `community`